# How can I solve 404 not found error when trying to retrieve some data from route?

Tags: laravel

I want some data shown in json format which will be retrieved via id from local database by get method. But when I pass the id through url and hit enter, it gives me a "404 not found" error? How can I resolve this problem?

My get route is listed in route list.  I've also tried postman to check the get method but in vain! "http://localhost/public/districts/1 is the url.

web.php:

```
Route::get('districts/{$id}', function ($id) {
    return App\Models\District::where('division_id', $id)->get();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route name should be `districts/{id}` , not `{$id}`

as seen here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Did you try http://localhost/districts/1 or http://localhost/api/districts/1? The `public` folder is not included in the url normally.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. http://localhost/lsapp/public/districts/1 is my url.

Comment: In that case did you try http://localhost/lsapp/districts/1 or http://localhost/lsapp/api/districts/1?

Comment: Yes and resulting in "Object not found"

Comment: Do you have any other routes besides `/` that do work? If not then it's probably an issue with the webserver (apache/nginx) setup

Comment: Route::get('/category/{id}', 'Frontend\CategoriesController@show')->name('categories.show'); This works fine. What should I do sir if it is the issue of webserver.

Comment: If you use Nginx as a webserver, then you could look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment) for an example configuration. Another issue could be that the  route itself does not work as intented. Could you try replacing `return App\Models\District::where('division_id', $id)->get();` with something like `return "Hello world"`? See if that shows up? That'll narrow down the issue somewhat